# Managing javascript without refreshing DOM in singlepage webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications

I am currently building a single page web app and running into a few issues which I think are all related to the same thing.

In short, I use ajax to pull in new content and a simple jquery .remove() to remove the old content.

I am finding the issue to be that I am removing off old javascript and bringing on new javascript (for the front end functionality of the new content, button clicks and things of the like). The old javascript still seems to be in the dom and running, which is causing issues with the new javascript. I am not refreshing the page, and would like to avoid refreshing it.

I did some poking around, it seems stuff like backbone.js might have a handle on this. I would like to stick with what I am currently using if possible. So in short, is it possible to remove that old javascript from the dom? Or anything close to something like that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Providing some code examples would be helpful. I kind of get what you're saying but there's no way to truly answer your question without it. As your question stands the answer is "Maybe."

Comment: I'm more than happy to show whatever you need to see. What would be the best thing for you to see?

Comment: You might need to be more specific with what you're actually trying to do. JavaScript won't magically go away; once it's evaluated in the page context it's there until the page is gone. What *precisely* are you trying to "stop running"?

Comment: @DaveNewton - It would be ideal if all the functions in the entire script tag I had just removed would stop running. I first realized this was an issue because I have the same buttons on multiple pages, they all do different things so the new and old functions were overlapping. I would love to find a way to remove the old javascript without reloading the page ( if its even possible ofcourse) because there is a ton of it coming in on each page to run quite a bit of stuff.

Comment: Bind your events in such a way that when you "leave" a "page" the events associated to that page are also removed.

Comment: @KevinB is there a way to do this removing the javascript from the DOM? because taking the actual script off the page isn't an issue, it's the fact that once it evaluates it sits in the DOM and i cannot (or don't know how) to remove it from there without refreshing the page.

Comment: No, "removing" the javascript from the dom does nothing. All you can do is "undo" what the javascript did, for example, removing elements, unbinding events, etc.